# Sort sql data using joined dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

In SQL Server 2014 I have a table `People` with a column `Country` (`int not null`). I want to sort rows by `Country`, but country is a int, I want to sort by country name. I don't have `Contries` table in db.

```
var countryDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
countryDict.Add((int)ECountry.AT, "Austria");
countryDict.Add((int)ECountry.IT, "Włochy");
.......

IQueryable<PeopleModel> result = _entity.People.Where(...)
```

Now I want to join my DbSet with dictionary with country id and country name

```
// there exception occurs
var resultWithCountryName = result
    .Join(
         countryDict,
         p => (int)p.Country,
         c => c.Key,
         (p, c) => new { p, CountryName = c.Value })
    .ToList();

result = resultWithCountryName
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Kraj)
    .Select(p => p.p)
    .AsQueryable();
```

After all I need pagination so I use this code for it.

```
        var resultList = result
            .Include(p => p.OtherTable) // nevermind
            .Skip(searchCriteria.Offset)
            .Take(searchCriteria.RowsOnPage)
            .ToList();
```

When I execute join statement I get exception

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
>   Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this
>   context.

My question is

1. why do I get this error?
2. Maybe my solution of this problem is wrong?

Comment: Basically EF doesn't know how to turn a `KeyValuePair` into SQL code.  You can use `AsEnumerable` before the `Join`, but that will run the SQL for `result` and the `Join` will be done in memory instead of on the DB.

Comment: Add a `Countries` table to your database and establish a foreign key relationship between your `People` table and the new `Countries` table - simplest and most reliable solution by far ....

Answer (score 0):

Probably give .ToList()/AsEnumerable()/AsQueryable() to the end of People query.

```
IQueryable<PeopleModel> result = _entity.People.Where(...).ToList();
```

Comment: It not working, if I remove convert to list, this expetion occurs when I try to get data

Comment: @Jacek What exception are you getting when you give .tolist() ?

Comment: The same: "Unable to create a constant value of type "

Comment: I believe the culprit is IQueryable<PeopleModel> make sure you have same datatype on both the sides.